# Problem when using observable object in FormGroup

Tags: angular

I am running into a problem which I can’t find a fix for. I have a function which creates my FormGroup and also creates the form fields and validators. The validators are custom validators and require a value from a observable and that’s where my problem starts.

Currently I call the function that creates FormGroup in the constructor part and then I create subscribe to my observable in the onNgInit. Doing so my code complains that the data which I am getting from my observable is unknown. That’s because the form function refers to stuff which has not been called. If I move the form function to after my observable code I get error that that I need to have a FormGroup.

So what is the best approach to make sure the form code can run and has access to the object returned by the observable ? Or would it be best to create initially an object with empty data so form can find the values and then have the subscription update it?

```js
paswdProfile$: Observable<IPasswordProfile>
paswdProfile: IPasswordProfile

constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PasswordComponent>,
        private adminService: AdminService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private cbLookupService: CouchbaseLookupService,
        private router: Router, private dialog: MatDialog, private toasterService: ToasterService, private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.passwordForm = this.createPasswordForm()
}



ngOnInit() {
    this.paswdProfile$ = this.adminService.getPasswordProfile("8084ea42-633e-4c28-bc7a-372aa58a4d1c")
    this.paswdProfile$.subscribe(res => {this.paswdProfile = res[0]})
    console.log(this.paswdProfile)
}

createPasswordForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group(
      {
        oldPassword : [ null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        newPassword: [
          null,
          Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            // check whether the entered password has a number
            CustomValidators.patternValidator(/\d/g, this.paswdProfile.numbers , {
              hasNumber: true
            })
          ])
        ],
      },
    );
}
```

[image: Pic of Object]

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: I updated question with some code

Comment: So you want to assign initial values to form from your response? If not can you please exactly pin point where to take a look?

Answer (score 1):

i think i found the solution, i added a hasData to the form which by default is false. Then to make it work i added the createPasswordForm to the subscription as well as the this.hasData = true. On the Template i added *ngIf="hasData" so the template only renders when there is Data.

```
this.paswdProfile$.subscribe(res => {this.paswdProfile = res, 
                                        this.passwordForm = this.createPasswordForm(), this.hasData = true})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the validator you could check if the observable already exists. If not return null (no error).  During setup it will not validate but the validator will not have to validate anything yet so that is no problem. During the use of the form the subscription will exist and thus apply  your logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
paswdProfile$: Observable<IPasswordProfile>
paswdProfile: IPasswordProfile

constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PasswordComponent>,
        private adminService: AdminService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private cbLookupService: CouchbaseLookupService,
        private router: Router, private dialog: MatDialog, private toasterService: ToasterService, private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.passwordForm = this.createPasswordForm()
}



ngOnInit() {
    this.paswdProfile$ = this.adminService.getPasswordProfile("8084ea42-633e-4c28-bc7a-372aa58a4d1c")
    this.paswdProfile$.subscribe(res => {this.paswdProfile = res[0]})
    console.log(this.paswdProfile)
}

createPasswordForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group(
      {
        oldPassword : [ null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        newPassword: [
          null,
          Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            // check whether the entered password has a number
            this.anAsyncValidator.bind(this)
          ])
        ],
      },
    );
}

anAsyncValidator(c: any) {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        this.paswdProfile$.subscribe(res => {
            this.paswdProfile = res[0]
            observer.next(CustomValidators.patternValidator(
                 /\d/g, 
                 this.paswdProfile.numbers , 
                 {
                     hasNumber: true
                 })(c)
            )
        })
    })
}
```

This code might not exactly work, but should at least give you an idea to fix your issue using custom async validators.